# Can a custom django admin class add items to a model's ManyToMany field?

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to automatically add some items to a model's ManyToMany field when it is saved in the Django admin UI.  However, calling model.many2manyfield.add() is failing silently

my django app's models.py

```
...
class Dashboard(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    url = models.TextField()
    graphs = models.ManyToManyField(Graph, null=True, blank=True)
```

my django app's admin.py

```
from models import Dashboard
...
class DashboardAdmin(GraphAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, dashboard, form, change):
        dashboard.save()
        graphite_util.sync_dashboard_graphs(dashboard)

...
admin.site.register(Dashboard, DashboardAdmin)
```

from graphite_util.py:

```
def sync_dashboard_graphs(dashboard):
    print "Syncing %s " % dashboard

    ...
            graph = None
            try:
                graph = Graph.objects.get(url=url)
            except Graph.DoesNotExist:
                graph = Graph()
                graph.url = url
                graph.save()
            print "adding graph %s to dashboard %s" %(graph, dashboard)
            dashboard.graphs.add(graph) #TODO: why does this fail silently?
```

Is what I want to do somehow illegal?  If so, are there other options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle it should work; however, you've got some inconsistencies in your code. For example, you're looking up the graph based on `url`. You've redacted part of your code, so it's possible you created the variable in the missing part, but I'm not sure where you would have gotten that info from; you have no access to the `request` from this method.

However, you could pass the request in to the method from where it's called in `save_model` because the request is available there.

Additionally, if you're simply going to create a graph in the except block, you're better off using `get_or_create`.

```
graph = Graph.objects.get_or_create(url=url)
```

It basically does the same thing, but much more concisely.